# What are the different custom scenarios for Age Of Empires 2?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I've been a member of GameRanger for a while, and I am familiar with RM - Random Map, and CBA - Castle Blood Auto, but I have noticed other game types such as Path Blood and Michi.

Can you give me a quick overview of each type of game that there is?

The community isn't great with new players, like myself!

Comment: Michi is a random map, not a scen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Age of Empires 2 scenarios, but I found [a list of scenarios with explanations](http://web.archive.org/web/20101021073657/http://www.gaminglan.net/2008/09/age-of-empires-scenarios-complete-help.html) which includes Path Blood at a blog called Gaming Lan.

It doesn't include Michi, but there's an explanation up at Urban Dictionary.

> ... a type of game map that uses impassable terrain (usually forest) to prevent players from rushing or coming into contact until the intervening terrain is cleared.

Comment: More scenario maps can be found here http://soldierofortune2.free.fr/aoe2/scenario/

Comment: Link rot - the answer now only answers half of the question, as the link that explained the other half is dead.

Comment: Updated the link to point to an archive of the original.

Answer (score 3):

Path blood is a custom scenario, completely different from RM/Dm.

You have no villagers, or a town center, and instead you just fight with units out of a "spawn" They keep coming untill you lose your tower.

In a "Blood"

the basics are the more kills you get= the better units
razings= rewards

and to win you have to kill everyone else's main tower